# Android automated battery consumption tests

Tags: android, automated-tests, battery

I want to build a CI script that along with testing my application will measure battery consuption. 
I have found Battery Historian, but a html report is not what i expect. I would like to detect automatically that today build causes >10% battery usage than yestarday's. Is that possible?

Comment: I would not expect you to be able to get a reliable test, since you do not control everything that consumes power on your test device. Also, battery charge granularity is fairly coarse, so you would need to run tests for a fairly long period of time to detect significant differences in power usage.

Comment: That is true. My goal is to test mainly background services